# API Observable with dynamic caching

Tags: scala, reactive-programming, rx-java

An API I'm polling has a field that defines the time that value is cached, `cachedUntil`. The goal is to create an Observable that polls and emits an event every time the cache has expired. The thing that distinguishes this case, is that the caching is not regular. I.e. `Observable.interval` does not apply.

In what ways is it possible to implement an Observable that has this behaviour?

The following snippet gives a function that polls the API, emits the requested events and return the `cachedUntil` delay to the next call.

```
def getContracts(subscriber: Subscriber[Set[EveContract]]): Option[Long] = {
    logger.debug("Fetching new contracts")
    try {
        val response = parser.getResponse(auth)
        if(response == null) {
            subscriber.onError(new RuntimeException("Unable to fetch contracts from EVE servers"))
            None
        }
        else if(response.hasError) {
            logger.error(response.getError.toString)
            subscriber.onError(new RuntimeException(response.getError.toString))
            None
        } else {
            subscriber.onNext(response.getAll.toSet) // Emit new polled data
            Some(response.getCachedUntil.getTime - new Date().getTime) // Return the cache delay
        }
    } catch {
        case aex: ApiException ⇒
            logger.error("An error occurred when querying the EVE API.")
            logger.debug("ApiException: ", aex)
            subscriber.onError(aex)
            None
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use Scheduler workers to reschedule a call to`getContracts`:

```
Observable[Set[EveContract]](observer ⇒ {
    val worker = Schedulers.newThread().createWorker()
    def scheduleContracts(delay: Long) {
        worker.schedule(new Action0 {
            override def call(){
                if(!observer.isUnsubscribed) {
                    val delay = getContracts(observer)
                    delay match {
                        // Reschedule a contract fetch after time d has passed.
                        case Some(d) ⇒
                            logger.debug(s"Rescheduling contract fetch in: ${d / 1000} s")
                            scheduleContracts(d)
                        case _ ⇒
                            // Otherwise do nothing
                            logger.debug("Not rescheduling contract fetch, an error has occured.")
                    }
                } else {
                    logger.trace("Subscriber has unsubscribed.")
                }
            }
        }, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    }
    scheduleContracts(0L)
})
```

However, I'm very interested in possible other solutions.